# get sum of interval between two DateTimeFields

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, sqlite, django-1.7

I have a `Booking` model with a `book_start` and `book_end` field, both being `DateTimeField`s. My goal is to get all booked hours (so basically the sum of intervals between all `book_start` and `book_end` fields). Is this possible with the framework somehow, or do I have to tell this programatically (e.g. read *all* timestamps, calculate the interval between them, and derive the sum from this)?

Answer (score 0):

you can try with [`.extra()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra)

```
Booking.objects.all().extra(select={'bookedhours': 'SUM(booking_end  - booking_start) * 3600'}).values('bookedhours')
```

this generates a query like:

```
SELECT (SUM(booking_end  - booking_start)) AS `bookedhours` FROM `my_application_booking`
```

I'm not really sure on the unit of the result, you should test that.

Comment: That's what I'm trying now, the problem is that I need to use SQLite's strftime() function with a '%s' passed as a parameter: 'booked_amount': 'strftime(\'%s\', end_ts) - strftime(\'%s\', start_ts)' Unfortunately I haven't found The Pytthon/Django way to achieve this (I get StopIteration in the Django shell)

Comment: @GergelyPolonkai as a side note you can inspect the generate query by printing the queryset.query field and try that in a dbshell